# Excel Concatenate Cells while adding characters and skipping Empty cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am not a programmer, but doing Excel work for a small library. We have these fields in an excel sheet:

```
John  | J   | Smith | BMI   | 123 | 100 |
Sarah |  P  | Crown | ASCAP | 564 | 100 |
Tommy |  T  | Stew  | BMI   | 134 | 100 |
Suzy  | S   | Smith | BMI   | 678 | 50  | 
John  | J   | Smith | BMI   | 123 | 50
```

What I would like to be able to combine any of the cells (in the same row)into one cell that would read like this:

```
John J Smith, (BMI), 100%, IPI 123
```

or

```
Suzy S Smith, (BMI), 50%, IPI 678  | John J Smith (BMI), 50% IPI 123
```

I figured out how to use the Concatenate function to do this, but it doesn't skip empty cells, and I get extra "|" or "()" in those spots. I also found the =StringConCat topic, and that works great for skipping, but I can't figure out how to add the extra characters.

Any help would be most appreciated.
Thank you!!

EDIT: Thanks for the quick responses so far. I should be more clear -

- the pipes in my example were only to designate different cells - they are not actual characters in the cells (thanks for converting it to a table for me, Bruce). The only Pipe character I would like to use is in the results, as in my example between Suzy and John.
- There will rarely be more than 2 entries on the same result line, but it is possible. Mostly it will be to composers that are sharing the credit. But there is a chance that they will work on a Public Domain song and I have to list "Traditional" or maybe "Mozart" as another composer.

Sorry that I don't know enough to ask my question as intelligently as I should. Just learning how to do this, and trying to figure it out as I go.

Thanks again!

Comment: (What version of Excel are you in? If it's 2016, you can use `=TextJoin()`.)

Comment: Is it expected to have 2 entries on the same line? Will there be more than 2? Are the number of fields for each entry set? If so using VBA you would just have to split by " | " (space, pipe, space) into an array. Iterate through it, test for empty strings, format string and spit out.

Comment: Thanks - i edited my initial question, but there is a rare case where there would be three composers listed.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I will investigate Text Join.

Comment: It doesn't seem like Text Join works on my Mac edition. I tried it and it gives me a NAME error. I looked for the formula function and I only have TEXT as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the extra spaces, use substitute to get rid of empties.

So, if your code is `=concatenate(A1,B1,C1)` and your 'empty spaces' are "| " then edit your formula to become `=substitute(concatenate(A1,B1,C1),"| ","")`

You can even stack the substitutes to add more possible 'empties', like "  " (two spaces) or the like. `=substitute(substitute(concatenate(A1,B1,C1),"| ",""),"  ","")`